Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime.Extensions
I've tried reinstalling the package from nuget (mutiple versions)
I've tried reinstalling visual studio 2022
The Project is running on .net 4.7.2.
I tried switching to .net 4.8
I've also tried adding this to web.config
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Extensions" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1" newVersion="4.3.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>

Nothing helped
it appears to be related to typescript. I tried removing node.js developement component from vs installation. didn't help
Here's the full error
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "CheckFileSystemCaseSensitive" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 

'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at TypeScript.Tasks.CheckFileSystemCaseSensitive.get_IsUnix()
   at TypeScript.Tasks.CheckFileSystemCaseSensitive.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. BinaNewWebApp   

    


If you think it is related to typescript, reinstall the TypeScript SDK by going to Visual Studio Installer and checking the TypeScript development workload under "Individual components" in Visual Studio setup. Ensure the TypeScript versions match what your project requires.
Have you tried redirecting to System.Runtime.Extensions 4.0.10 and installing 4.0.10 from Nuget?

I tried intstalling  4.0.10 from nuget, didn't help. What do you mean by redirecting?

Do you have any other Nugert bags in your project? Sometimes, different NuGet packages might reference different versions of the same assembly. Go to the References tab (or Dependencies). Find System.Runtime.Extensions and check if there are multiple versions. If so, try updating them all to a consistent version (such as 4.3.1).
